# Rendering bug in WebKit browsers

Tags: javascript, extjs, rendering

In the project I currently work on we experience very strange rendering issue. The worst thing is that this issue emerges completely spontaneously and after several days of testing we haven't managed to find the sequence of actions wich would reproduce this issue. Here is an explanation of how this bug look like. Here is a screenshot of how the page should look like:

[image: Desired look]

But instead of this after some manipulations content block pops up so only the part of the content is visible and its look like:

[image: Issue]

The most strange thing is that such a position of the block is not based on values of CSS properties as shown by Web Inspector.

[image: Web inspector]

As you can see the CSS properties are ok, while the position of the block is not. This fact suggest me that it could be some rendering bug of the WebKit engine

The project is built using Ext JS 3.4 and it is a classical one-page web application. This issue was seen in the last versions of Chrome and Safari on Mac OS 10.7/10.8. Though due to the spontaneous nature of this issue it might be present in other browsers and platforms too.

Any piece of advice on how to debug such issues or how it could arise is welcome.

Comment: If it is a bug, then file it at http://crbug.com

Comment: Have you checked there are no errors generated by the Javascript?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sure, no JS errors present.

Comment: Can you share any code where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: how do you position your content tag. can you show us the css attribute of this element and the manipulations on it?

Comment: @w4rumy The problem is that we can't reproduce it stably, the issue is absolutely spontaneous.

Comment: @Safari I added a screenshot of Developer Tools at the moment when issue appears.

Comment: @probably you should give a little more attention here

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the computed style properties on that element?

Comment: @stuajc Computed properties were the same before and after bug visualization. This issue was definitely a WebKit rendering bug, since it vanished once browsers were updated after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if any of your code or Ext JS's code is using scrollIntoView method, we have seen similar issue when scrollIntoView is called on any element that does not have overflow set to auto and it is inside an clipped element that is probably placed relatively positioned.

It seems bug in webkit because it scrolls clipped element which is not happening in other browsers.

I also see two elements in same hierarchy which has overflow set to auto. And scrollIntoView is scrolling wrong element.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and safari on Mac are having problems with scrolling. If the element has been scrolled and the content changes, the scroll position is kept even if the content is not high enough to require a scrolling.

The work around we have found in our application is to resize the container (the one that has the scroll) so that it has the scrollbar (or else you cannot play with the scrolling properties) and then reset the scrolling, and the height.

```
$(container).css('height',1).scrollTop('1').css('height','');
```

Here is how we do it in jQuery. You will not even see a flickering :)

I am not sure if it is the problem, but this thing kept us on our feet for a while.

Answer (score 1):

i went through the same problem while working with a `sencha touch 2` app and because thats same as `ExtJS` i have a solution for you
this probably is a bug in the framework and this happens when the ExtJS renders the application before the browser populates mayb the correct `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and thus the viewport cannot take the correct width and height. this also explains the randomness of the event. This becomes more prominent when used on mobiles probably because of the limited resources and slow response.
the solution that i took to handle this mayb isnt a good one but i couldnt find a better one considering is a glitch in the framework itself
i poll for the correct `height` and `width` of the browser for around a sec after every say 100ms for the correct height and width of the window and if i find that the height OR width of the `viewport` isnt same i re adjust it. because you are working with ExtJS and app would run on high powered systems(as compared to mobile phones) i would recommend a smaller interval and then to be safe a larger time period to which it polls.
heres the code that i use currently edit according to your needs

```
var aId = setInterval(function () {
                    if (Ext.Viewport.getWidth() !== window.innerWidth || Ext.Viewport.getHeight() !== window.innerHeight) {
                        Ext.Viewport.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                        clearInterval(aId);
                    }
                    num = num + 1;
                    if (num > 10) {
                        clearInterval(aId);
                    }
                }, 100)
```

i currently use this code inside the `launch function` of the app. but you can also use this inside the `show` event of the `viewport` for which you should keep the interval time to minimum possible to avoid any lags.
with this if you think this app might be used on devices where the window height and width would be changed by the user (like that of mobile browser when the *orientation changes* or if you think user would change the `height` and `width` of the browser window). then just copy & paste the same code piece inside the viewports `resize event` so that it also polls and resizes viewport when the size of the viewport changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a clear:both; block after the toolbar div ?

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@bjornd it's pretty hard to debug without *any* code :)

Is the toolbar positioned and has the content an ID that's called in the URL? 
In other words: is there some link (e.g.) that triggers `#content` and has no `preventDefault()` etc? This would scroll the page probably.

I dunno, this was the first thing that came to mind.

It could also be the `toolbar` content that is (for some reason) no longer cleared or some change in the `content`'s `top` position (relative to another changed/removed element?)

Try and create a stripped-down test-case that contains the simplest of code but still triggers the bug. If you post that (through e.g. a Fiddle etc) we can have a proper look.

Comment: "Try and create a stripped-down test-case that contains the simplest of code but still triggers the bug" I can't do that because the issue isn't stable and can't be reproduced step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a css issue;

I've had a similar issue using equal height divs by setting a `padding-bottom: 99999px;` and  `margin-bottom: -99999px;`. Which workes fine in all cases, except when you use hashtag anchors to jump to a div further on the page. `<a href="#someDivFurtherOnThePage">Jump down</a>`.

In that case the top of the page clipped and started with the div I wanted to see.

Since you say the problem is pretty hard to track, this might be something to have a look at. The solution was to remove these 2 css lines and use another method of setting div heights.